# Spring is not recognizing my @Qualifier statement

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have two beans with identical types, I'm using Parent-Child jobs (one overrides the other).  When attempting to AutoConfigure them, I know I need to specify an @Qualifier statement so Spring can inject the right bean into my Test case.   I have done that like this:

> @Autowired
>       @Qualifier("LoadAcceptanceTestDataJob")
>       private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherUtils;

My job definition looks like this:

> ```
> <import resource="load-bms-job.xml"/>
> ```

```
<batch:job id="LoadAcceptanceTestDataJob" parent="LoadBMSJob">
    <batch:step id="AcceptanceDeleteAcctMap" parent="deleteAcctMap" next="AcceptanceDeleteCountrySkippingExclusion" />
    <batch:step id="AcceptanceDeleteCountrySkippingExclusion" parent="deleteCountrySkippingExclusion" next="AcceptanceDeleteBlueReportOut" />
    <batch:step id="AcceptanceDeleteBlueReportOut" parent="deleteBlueReportOut" next="AcceptanceDeleteShadowBMSContract" />
    <batch:step id="AcceptanceDeleteShadowBMSContract" parent="deleteShadowBMSContract" next="AcceptanceCountrySkippingExclusionStep" />

    <batch:step id="AcceptanceCountrySkippingExclusionStep" parent="countrySkippingExclusionStep" next="AcceptanceMappingFileLoadStep" />
    <batch:step id="AcceptanceMappingFileLoadStep" parent="mappingFileLoadStep" next="Override-ExtractAndLoad-BMS-Data-Step" />
    <batch:step id="Override-ExtractAndLoad-BMS-Data-Step" parent="ExtractAndLoad-BMS-Data-Step">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="BMSDataItemReaderCSV" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Here is my stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJob' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: LoadBMSJob,LoadAcceptanceTestDataJob
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: LoadBMSJob,LoadAcceptanceTestDataJob
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: `@Autowired @Qualifier("LoadAcceptanceTestDataJob") private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherUtils;` Is that like identical to that in your code or are they in new lines (3 lines total)?

Comment: Yes, correct, it just looks funny because of the formatting, but yes, three lines exactly as you have it above.

Comment: I tried changing the of Autowired and Qualifier... no difference.

Comment: Has your Been got the same name? `@Bean(name = "LoadAcceptanceTestDataJob")`?

Comment: I'm not using @Bean annotations anywhere...

Comment: I don't use the XML bean creation, so I can't help you with the exact code, but I would say check if `<batch:job id="LoadAcceptanceTestDataJob" parent="LoadBMSJob">` that line allow `name` parameter and if it does set it to `LoadAcceptanceTestDataJob` and try.  In annotation config you would have `@Bean(name = "LoadAcceptanceTestDataJob")` and then `@Qualifier("LoadAcceptanceTestDataJob")` where ever you're using that been.

Comment: I gave up and just stopped using Parent job, which side-stepped the problem.... cheesy but it works.  Need to move on - thx.